# Proof strategy - Borel $\sigma-$fields

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

How does one go about proving the following:

Every open set $A$ in the topological space $(\mathbb{R}^d,\|\cdot\|)$ (with the norm topology) is the union of all the open balls $B_\epsilon(q)$ whose center $q$ and radius $\epsilon>0$ are rational.

In fact, the result that I'm aiming at is to show that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, i.e. the Borel $\sigma-$field in $\mathbb{R}^d,d<\infty$ is the $\sigma-$field generated by the class of sets that are of the form

$$O:=\times_{j=1}^d(a_j,b_j]$$

with $a_j,b_j\in\mathbb{R},\forall j=1,\dots,d$.

Comment: The more general question in the context of a space $X$ doesn't make sense because $q$ would just be a point in $X$--how can it be "rational"? I understand you are aiming for $\mathbb R^n$ where this makes sense, though.

Comment: Right - thanks. I rephrased the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U:=\cup\left\{ B_{\varepsilon}\left(q\right)\mid q\in\mathbb{Q}^{d},\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0},B_{\varepsilon}\left(q\right)\subset A\right\} $

Then $U\subset A$.

If $a\in A$ then $B_{\delta}\left(a\right)\subset A$
for some $\delta>0$.

Then $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{Q}_{>0}$
exists with $\varepsilon<\frac{1}{2}\delta$, and $q\in\mathbb{Q}^{d}$ exists
with $\left\Vert a-q\right\Vert <\varepsilon$ since $\mathbb{Q}^{d}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Then $a\in B_{\varepsilon}\left(q\right)\subset B_{\delta}\left(a\right)\subset A$.

This because $x\in B_{\varepsilon}\left(q\right)$ implies that: $$\left\Vert x-a\right\Vert \leq\left\Vert x-q\right\Vert +\left\Vert a-q\right\Vert <2\varepsilon<\delta$$

Note that $B_{\varepsilon}\left(q\right)\subset U$ and consequently $a\in U$.

Prove is now that $A=U$.